# Magento 2 : override customer login.phtml file in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, customer, login, magento-2.0

I had developed "Hello world" extension in Magento 2.

I want to override Customer login form of core files. What is correct way for overriding Customer login  form file in Magento 2.

I have coded like this

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
    <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template"xsi:type="string">Namespace_Loginoverride::login.phtml</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

but above code does not work for me

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A few things:

- First, here's a link in the docs to [set block template](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template).
- Next, the documentation states that the `<action>` node is [deprecated](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act).
- Also, I found that I was able to accomplish the task you have asked about by following this page in the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html).

To successfully replace the `Magento_Customer::form/login.phml` template with a custom template:

1. Create the following directory structure `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/`
2. Add the template file `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml`
3. Add desired custom code within the `login.phtml` file.
4. Verify the custom theme is already in place (or enable it if you haven't already) by going to: `Admin panel`->`Content`->`Design Configuration`->`Your Store or Store View`. And sure your custom theme shows under `Applied Theme`
5. If you're not in developer mode, or if you are in developer mode and have manually deployed static content (`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`) then you'll want to clear your cache and `pub/static/` (except the .htaccess) directories. If you are in developer mode and haven't manually deployed static assets skip this step.
6. Refresh your `http://<YOUR_DOMAIN.COM>/customer/account/login/` page, or go visit it, and view the desired changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add below code inside layout file,

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
    <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Loginoverride::login.phtml</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

You must add to your **login.phtml** file inside below location **`app/code/Namespace/LoginOverride/view/frontend/templates/login.phtml`**

Comment: Thank you fro answer Rakesh, unfortunately it's not work for me , i have already done it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the following steps Not sure if you are still looking for the answer:
Step one is in your module create ->
view/frontend/templates/layout/customer_account_login.xml

You are only focusing on the login page so do the following

[image]

and 
view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

add what you change is

example: add the h1 tag and test it out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space in your code:

Instead of:

```
<argument name="template"xsi:type="string">Namespace_Loginoverride::login.phtml</argument>
```

It should be:

```
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Loginoverride::login.phtml</argument>
```

Also ensure that `app/code/Namespace/Loginoverride/view/frontend/templates/login.phtml` is the right path of your template.

Comment: Hello Raphael,Thank you for answer, i have add space but still it not working for me.

Comment: @bharatdesai is your layout file named `customer_account_login.xml` ?

Comment: yes, my layout file like this : 
Namespace/Loginoverride/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml

Comment: @bharatdesai did you try flushing `var/cache`, `var/generation` and `var/di` ?

Comment: yes, we have flush the  var/cache, var/genration, var/page_cache.