# How to override login.phtml in a custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, customer, login

How to override customer login.phtml file in custom module, whenever i try it not doing what I expected

Comment: add the codes you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the following steps Not sure if you are still looking for the answer:
Step one is in your module create ->
view/frontend/templates/layout/customer_account_login.xml

You are only focusing on the login page so do the following

[image]

and 
view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

add what you change is

example: add the h1 tag and test it out

[image]

Link to same question :[Magento 2 : override customer login.phtml file in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/magento-2-override-customer-login-phtml-file-in-custom-module)

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

Create XML file at in your custom extension :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml
```

Add below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::form/login.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create below file then add your conent here:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you I will use these two